# what is the advantages of Singleton pattern with static constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, singleton

I have some code as shown below. I guess it is `Singleton` pattern. Why do I need a static constructor. Also what is the advantages of this? Thanks for your reply ...

```
  public sealed class Myclass
  {
    static Myclass()
    {
        Myclass.Application = new Myclass();
    }

    protected Myclass()
    {

    }

    static Myclass _application;

    public static Myclass Application
    {
        get { return Myclass._application; }
        protected set { Myclass._application = value; }
    }

    string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name}
        protected set { _name= value; }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To start with, this class is somewhat odd for having a *protected* constructor. It's not a fatal flaw given that it's sealed, but it's distinctly odd.

There's a [potential difference in timing](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/BeforeFieldInit.aspx) between this code and the nearly-equivalent use of a static variable initializer:

```
static readonly Myclass _application = new Myclass();
```

(There's no need for a setter in this case, of course.)

You can't do that with an automatically implemented property though.

Using static initialization in *some* form gets you "free" thread-safety - you don't need to do any locking in order to get lazy initialization.

You may find my [singleton implementation article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) interesting for more options.

Answer (score 0):

There is no immediate advantage in the static constructor as opposed to a lazy-instantiated on get approach, other than thread safety as pointed out by Jon Skeet's answer. This may or may not be relevant in your situation, though you don't specify anything. It just makes the code look different, but is going to result in the same functionality.

The "advantage" of the singleton pattern is that is allows easy access to a single instance of a class, basically a sort of "globally" accessible instance of the class.

I say "advantage" as there are many discussions about the Singleton pattern being an anti-pattern. I am on the fence. In a small application this can function OK and most of the proposed alternative solutions involve Dependency Injection frameworks (often sometimes with the life-span of "Singleton"!), which may be impractical on smaller apps.

Just a note, having a `sealed` class with `protected` members is pointless - sealed classes cannot be inherited.

Answer (score 0):

If you write in this way you can use  *auto* property and do not actually *implement* it.

Say like this:

```
 public sealed class Myclass
 {
        static Myclass()
        {
            Myclass.Application = new Myclass();
        }

       .....
        public static Myclass Application {get;set;}
        ...


}
```

Basically, there is no any *practcal* advantage if not like this one: code-style.

Answer (score 0):

Usage of a type ctor here is a guarantee that singleton instance will be initialized once. It's more simple that double-checked lock pattern, when implementing lazy singleton initialization, but it has disadvantage the same reason - singleton creation may be very expensive, and singleton may never be used during app lifetime.

Comment: If the singleton is never used, then the type won't be initialized, so the expense won't be incurred.

Comment: For this code sample - yes, you're right. My answer was related to more common case... e.g. when class have public static method.

Comment: I don't find that a common case, actually - I usually see singletons with a single public static member to get the instance, and then everything else as instance members. This improves consistency aside from anything else. You can use a private "holder" class for lazy initialization in this case though - see the fifth option in the article linked near the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks, but I prefer to not invent the wheel and use option 6... Lazy<T>.

Comment: Which is why option 6 is present and even recommended at the bottom. It doesn't help if you're not using .NET 4 though, and I probably wouldn't use it unless I *did* have extra static methods which I wanted to execute without initializing the singleton. (Heck, I tend to avoid the singleton pattern anyway.) My point is that performing the checking in the "getter" (with either always-locking or double-checked-locking) is almost *never* the preferred option these days.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create the instance of the class somewhere, and that can either be in a static constructor, or in the property that gets the instance.

Anyhow, it's not a good code example that you have found.

- It has `protected` members even though it's `sealed`, which only makes the code confusing. They should be `private`.
- If you look at the `Name` property you will notice that it's impossible to set it, so it will always be `null`.

Answer (score -1):

static constructor it gets called during the loading of the assembly...

**EDIT:**
thanks jon  I was wrong...
now i understand static constructors in C# are specified to execute only when an instance of the class is created or a static member is referenced..

Comment: No it doesn't. It's only executed when the type is first *used*. See http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/BeforeFieldInit.aspx